# HTML DOM add a class upon object property change

Tags: javascript, html, dom

What i have in my hands is a class that takes some input:

```
constructor(firstName,lastName,phone,email) {
    this.firstName=firstName
    this.lastName=lastName
    this.phone=phone
    this.email=email
    this.online=false
}
```

And a function that appends the given input to the page. However how do i listen for `this.online` change after i have appended the elements? Example.
`let contacts = [new Contact("Ivan", "Ivanov", "0888 123 456", "i.ivanov@gmail.com")]`
and then `contacts[0].online=true` If the online property is set to true to do something, in my case add a class to the main body.
I've thought about eventListeners but i don't know how to make them listen for object property change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just make a function that appends the given input to the page and after you set the online property to `true` call the function right after that.